# Reverse words of a sentence using stack from c++ standard library

Tags: c++, stack

I am trying to reverse words of each sentence using `std::stack` from the c++ standard library.

The input file contents are:

> 3
>   foobar
>   this is a test
>   all your base

So the answer should be:

> foobar
>   test a is this
>   base your all

But instead, the answer is:

> foobar
>   test test test test
>   base base base base

I cannot figure out why. Following is the code:

```
#include <cstdio>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <fstream>
#include <cstring>
#include <stack>

using namespace std;

int main() {
  FILE *fp, *fpo;
  fp = fopen("test.in", "r");
  int tests;
  fscanf(fp, "%d", &tests);
  char ch;
  fscanf(fp, "%c", &ch); 
  for (int i = 0; i < tests; i++) {
    char *letters;
    letters = (char*)calloc(1000, sizeof(char));
    stack <char*> words;
    fscanf(fp, "%s", letters); fscanf(fp, "%c", &ch);

    while (ch != '\n' && ch != EOF) {
      words.push(letters); printf(" %s", words.top());
      fscanf(fp, "%s", letters); fscanf(fp, "%c", &ch);
    }
    words.push(letters); printf(" %s", words.top());
    printf("  --  ");
    while (!words.empty()) {
      printf(" %s", words.top());
      words.pop();
    }
    printf("\n");
    free(letters);
  }
  fclose(fp);  
}
```

Comment: Why don't you use `<fstream>`?

Comment: You're apparently calling your same addresses to and from the stack again and again,

Comment: Why do you mix C and C++ in this (nasty) way?

Comment: (!words.empty()) woops

Comment: I thought you said you were learning C++?

Comment: Oh my, all those `char*` :(

Comment: What have you done!?!?!

Comment: You almost certainly don't mean [STL](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/stl/info), but the c++ standard library.

Comment: If you insist on a stack http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/812bbe8c7d2cac92, but I'd personally prefer http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/bc4c239e60f203e0. This is inspiration for C++

Comment: Using `fscanf(fd, "%c, ...)` to skip over an end of line is inherently unsafe. Just add a (non visible) space after 3 or foobar and look what happens...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Please don't mix **C** and **C++** this way. It is almost unreadable. Some guidelines:

- don't use raw char arrays for strings, use: [std::string](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string)
- use C++ facility to read lines: [std::getline](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/getline)
- to use the previous function you will need to use a C++ file stream [std::ifstream](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ifstream) .
- once you read a line you can use a [std::stringstream](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_stringstream) and a `std::string` to extract each word from the line.
- you can then push each word on the stack and then pop to reverse the whole string.

Answer (score 1):

As others say in comments, your code is *bad*:

- you use a high level c++ stack, but only store `char *` in it, when you could use `std::string`
- you use C standard library for IO, when you could use C++ library (`std::stringstream` would help here)
- you input is line oriented and you use `fscanf` instead of `fgets` (or better `getline` as your question is tagged c++)

But the actual cause of your error is simply that you are storing a `char *` in your stack, that always point to the same char array, instead of allocating a new array for each word. So:

- you find a word in letters
- you store only the address of letters **not** its content
- you erase letters with next word

and your stack contains n copies of the address of letters each pointing to the same array of last word.

You should either:

- use malloc or strdup to allocate a new array for each word (the C way) - and consistently free each allocated array
- use `std::string`, and better a `stack<string>` (the C++ way) to let the C++ library manage allocation and deallocation for you.

There can be good reasons to use C library functions in a C++ program (size or performance constraints in a program that already uses C code, assignement to do so), but unless it is the case, the high level C++ library is simpler to use with less risk of errors than the low level C one.

TL/DR: If you had used C++ library (getline, std::string, iostream, stringstream, stack) the library itself would have saved you from that error.